# Cardano Node: Connection reset by peer problem ---

Tags: cardano-node, cardano-db-sync

My cardano node was running normal and all of sudden I get this error,
**ErrorPolicySuspendPeer (Just (ApplicationExceptionTrace (MuxError (MuxIOException Network.Socket.recvBuf: resource vanished (Connection reset by peer)) "(recv errored)"))) 20s 20s**

I have tried restarting the node, but the error is same.
Note: I am using testnet.
Updated Status:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide us with your node version : `cardano-node --version`
And the slot and epoch number at which your node stopped syncing. Thanks

The testnet recently hard-forked into Alonzo era and if your node isn't at version `1.29.0` then you'll have issues syncing past the hardfork.
If indeed your node is outdated, download the latest binaries here : [Binaries 1.29.0](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node#linux-executable)

Also make sure to get the latest configuration files at : [Config files](https://hydra.iohk.io/build/7370192/download/1/index.html)

A common fix is also to delete the database folder containing `immutable`, `ledger`, ...
So try this if the above doesn't apply or solve your issue (this will re-sync your node from epoch 1).

Comment: This was helpful to some extent. I updated to 1.29. My node is fully synced, but when i run cardano-wallet serve. I get this error
cardano-wallet: ExceptionInLinkedThread (ThreadId 15) DecoderFailure

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with cardano-wallet, though I would also suggest checking that it is up to date. Good luck

Comment: removing the db folders `immutable` and `ledger` was enough for me, although I'm at version 1.27. After deleting them I re-ran `cardano-node run ...`
Glad I didn't need to reinstall all of that lol, took me quite some time just yesterday